# Azure Functions with Event Grid Trigger Scale Up

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

If my Azure Functions App has multiple instances that are working, I mean if it scales up, will event grid, trigger to all instances, or just one of them?

Comment: Think about it, what would be the point of scaling out if everything would still be send to just one instance?

Comment: @PeterBons What I want to know is, does Event Grid load balance events between Azure Functions App instances?

Answer (score 0):

They trigger functions from the function app, and Event Grid triggers aren't natively supported in an internal load balancer App Service Environment. The trigger uses an HTTP request that can't reach the function app without a gateway into the virtual network.

Have a look on the Microsoft documentation about [overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid) and Event Grid, function app with C# code to [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?tabs=csharp%2Cbash) our functions.

Comment Update:
Usually Event Grid triggers the Functions in function app.
Now coming to the instances of the function app depends on the scaling behaviors of the various hosting plans. (**Azure Functions infrastructure scales CPU and memory resources by adding additional instances of the Functions host, based on the number of incoming trigger events.**) Which means, depends on the load from the incoming triggers function app will scale in and out accordingly.

Maximum scale out limit for Consumption App:

[image]

Refer to Azure function scaling and hosting [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#scale)

Comment: You mean that each function that subscribed to the same topic in Azure Functions App instances, process the same event? How can I prove this in the easiest way? I read these documents before, but there isn't any information about my question's answer, unfortunately.

Comment: @Orhun - Edited my answer and added required information to your comment, thanks.